# How to fix Very Slow Query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

- **MongoDB shell version v4.0.5**

: Very Slow Query | Taking time in fetching | Data Size : 2-3 Million documents in a collection and there are around 13-15 such collections.

- **System Configuration**

: Architecture:
 x86_64 CPU op-mode(s):
 32-bit, 64-bit Byte Order:
 Little Endian CPU(s):
 6 On-line CPU(s) list:
 0-5 Thread(s) per core:
 1 Core(s) per socket:
 6 Socket(s):
 1 NUMA node(s):
 1 Vendor ID:
 GenuineIntel CPU family:
 6 Model:
 79 Stepping:
 1 CPU MHz:
 2097.570 BogoMIPS:
 4195.14 Hypervisor vendor:
 VMware Virtualization type:
 full L1d cache:
 32K L1i cache:
 32K L2 cache:
 256K L3 cache:
 20480K NUMA node0 CPU(s): 0-5

MemTotal: 16432268 kB

I have done indexing on the tables and that is working fine but still, the system is taking a lot of time:

**Query:**

```
db.vnms_vccells_5.find({auid:"<1e000097>",
        hub_ip:"10.252.0.105",sector_ip:"<1e000046>", 
        last_updated_time:{$gt:"2016-12-24 05:49:00"}})
    .explain("executionStats")
```

**Below is the query planner:**

```
{
    "queryPlanner": {
        "plannerVersion": 1,
        "namespace": "opennms.vnms_vccells_5",
        "indexFilterSet": false,
        "parsedQuery": {
            "$and": [{
                "auid": {
                    "$eq": "<1e000097>"
                }
            }, {
                "hub_ip": {
                    "$eq": "10.252.0.105"
                }
            }, {
                "sector_ip": {
                    "$eq": "<1e000046>"
                }
            }, {
                "last_updated_time": {
                    "$gt": "2016-12-24 05:49:00"
                }
            }]
        },
        "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern": {
                    "auid": 1,
                    "hub_ip": 1,
                    "sector_ip": 1,
                    "last_updated_time": -1
                },
                "indexName": "auid_1_hub_ip_1_sector_ip_1_last_updated_time_-1",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "auid": [],
                    "hub_ip": [],
                    "sector_ip": [],
                    "last_updated_time": []
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "auid": ["[\"<1e000097>\", \"<1e000097>\"]"],
                    "hub_ip": ["[\"10.252.0.105\", \"10.252.0.105\"]"],
                    "sector_ip": ["[\"<1e000046>\", \"<1e000046>\"]"],
                    "last_updated_time": ["({}, \"2016-12-24 05:49:00\")"]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans": []
    },
    "executionStats": {
        "executionSuccess": true,
        "nReturned": 28788,
        "executionTimeMillis": 34989,
        "totalKeysExamined": 28788,
        "totalDocsExamined": 28788,
        "executionStages": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "nReturned": 28788,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 34475,
            "works": 28789,
            "advanced": 28788,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 1039,
            "restoreState": 1039,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "invalidates": 0,
            "docsExamined": 28788,
            "alreadyHasObj": 0,
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned": 28788,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 7730,
                "works": 28789,
                "advanced": 28788,
                "needTime": 0,
                "needYield": 0,
                "saveState": 1039,
                "restoreState": 1039,
                "isEOF": 1,
                "invalidates": 0,
                "keyPattern": {
                    "auid": 1,
                    "hub_ip": 1,
                    "sector_ip": 1,
                    "last_updated_time": -1
                },
                "indexName": "auid_1_hub_ip_1_sector_ip_1_last_updated_time_-1",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "auid": [],
                    "hub_ip": [],
                    "sector_ip": [],
                    "last_updated_time": []
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "auid": ["[\"<1e000097>\", \"<1e000097>\"]"],
                    "hub_ip": ["[\"10.252.0.105\", \"10.252.0.105\"]"],
                    "sector_ip": ["[\"<1e000046>\", \"<1e000046>\"]"],
                    "last_updated_time": ["({}, \"2016-12-24 05:49:00\")"]
                },
                "keysExamined": 28788,
                "seeks": 1,
                "dupsTested": 0,
                "dupsDropped": 0,
                "seenInvalidated": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo": {
        "host": "vnms",
        "port": 27017,
        "version": "4.0.5",
        "gitVersion": "3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412"
    },
    "ok": 1
}
```

**mongostat data:**

```
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize   res qrw arw net_in net_out conn                time
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     3|0  0.0% 80.0%       0 5.26G 3.52G 0|0 3|0   254b    101k    7 Jan 23 10:20:41.082
```

Comment: You must have slow disks.  Index is proper from "totalKeysExamined" : 28788, "totalDocsExamined" : 28788.  low queue, vsize and res.

Comment: Thank you Dev for formating the question.

Comment: Thank you @simagix for the reply below is the result for disk health :                                0+1 records in 0+1 records out 231147560 bytes (231 MB) copied, 34.7774 s, 6.6 MB/s This is the result by the dd command

Comment: sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
  /dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   7778 MB in  1.99 seconds = 3910.73 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  12 MB in  3.30 seconds =   3.64 MB/sec         
 @simagix Can you please help me to find out that these results for the disk are upto mark or not? TIA

Comment: @simagix Hi, One observation which is very weird is that, if I apply indexes to all the collections after that system become slow, probably indexes are taking memory and causing slowness? Not Sure. Please suggest.TIA

Comment: What storage engine are you applying? consider WiredTiger! If the problem is fetching one of  these things can cause problems... IO, Network or disks. Consider this related to indexes: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/ also consider fetching data in a paged way using skip and limit operators.

Answer (score 0):

The query performance is limited by your resources.  Here are a few tips

1. check your resources by following the [Operations Checklists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-checklist-operations/).
2. From the query plan, not only fetching docs was slow, examining indexes keys was also slow.  You need to [Ensure Indexes Fit in RAM](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/).
3. Applying additional random indexes does not help and you can cause high numbers of page faults.  You can use [$indexStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/) to check your indexes usages.
4. Try MongoDB's [Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager) to help collect performance metrics.  It offers free trial.
5. Query-wise, project only the fields you need instead of fetching the entire document.